# SSIS Component InputColumnCollection empty

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I'm trying to create a custom SSIS destination component.

In the `PreExecute` or `ProcessInput` method I'm trying to read the columns from

```
ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[0].InputColumnCollection
```

but its length zero.

I do have a single input in `InputCollection` so that is working fine. But `InputColumnCollection` is empty.

Processing the actual rows are not a problem. I can read them and thier datatypes. But i just can't seem to figure out how i get what column index belongs to which column in the row since i have no column names.

So I can read my input from the data source but have no clue what data is which since I have no input column names.

All the examples I've seen online uses `InputColumnCollection`.

Comment: Have you ticked/selected your input columns on the 'Input Columns' tab?

Comment: @ChrisMack No, my component has no graphical user interface, it fails with some error 'Stream' is null if i try to open its editor or adv. editor. But i found out VirtualInputColumnCollection is not empty and i can use that.  But i dont know what the difference is between the two Virtual and non virtual inputcolumncollections?